# no operator found error with boost read_xml function

Tags: c++, boost, readxml, boost-propertytree

I am trying to read an xml file into a ptree using read_xml function as below:

```
read_xml(myFile, myPtree, boost::property_tree::xml_parser::trim_whitespace);
```

Here myFile is an `std::string` and myPtree is a `basic_ptree<std::string, std::wstring>.`

It gives me the following error when building:

```
xml_parser_read_rapidxml.hpp(48): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
         with
          [
              _Elem=char,
              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
          ]
```

Any pointers on what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get messages as shown, simply because there is no implicit conversion from `std::string` to `std::wstring`

In that case, match the string types or try to adjust the `basic_ptree` specialization

Since you're parsing from XML, and the XML parser supports only one string type, it is ***likely*** that you *need* to make the key and data string types identical.

You could use the string type matching the XML parser, and use a `translator_between<std::string, std::wstring>` to invoke the appropriate character set conversion

Comment: Thanks, Looks like that is my problem. It can read the xml file only using a single datatype. So modifying my basic_ptree to have same datatypes for key and data fixes the issue. But I need to modify all my keys to be std::wstring now. Let me see how it goes.